# Reconstruct a plane and keep UV intact

Tags: uv

This is probably simple, I want to remove some unused space since it takes up lightmap space in my game

[image]

Basicly I want to remove the red part but keep the green withsame texture cordinates so I need to correct UV somehow.

Mesh looks like this in blender 2.8

[image]

So basically I want to shrink down to the 3D cursor, but also remap UV.

edit: I solved it just because it was even measures. The wall is 4 meters tall and the wall I want is 1 meter. So i moved down the vertices, now the UV is wrong. Than I moved the top vertices in the UV mapping down from 1.0 to 0.25. Must be a more bullet proof way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a knife or loop cut to break the square in half, then delete the extra vertices.

Comment: Loop cut sounds like something I wanna to, can you tell me about the process? Thanks

Comment: i found some reasources about it. But I need to create my cut at exactly 1.0 meters from ground plane.

Comment: In that case, can you turn on snap to grid? https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/editing/transform/control/snap.html